# Batch renaming files in subfolder of working directory to sequence

Tags: r, rename

There are similar questions on Stack Overflow but none quite meets my specific needs.

I have a list of files with random names in a subfolder of my working directory, e.g. `working_directory/animals/photos`

The files are currently named:

```
Chicken.png
Moose.png
Cat.png
```

And I would like to rename them into the following (I have 5750 photos):

```
Animal1.png
Animal2.png
Animal3.png
...
Animal5750.png
```

I feel like there should be a simple solution but I can't quite figure out the coding for `file.rename` to do this, where most examples are for individual files, or files within the working directory.

This is my attempt from looking at examples on Stack Exchange, but this did not work:

```
original_path <- 'animals/photos'
renamed_list <- dir(path = original_path, pattern = '*.png')

sapply(X = renamed_list, FUN = function(x) {
  file.rename(paste0(original_path, x),
              paste0(original_path, 'Animal', substring(x, first = 1))) })
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have a function or dictionary that associated "chicken" and "moose" with "Animal"? Or is it the fact that the ***grand-parent*** directory is `../animals/..`?

Comment: Said differently, if `vec <- list.files("working_directory/animals", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE)`, then how do we know which level of parent directory should we be using?

Comment: The files are in the folder Animals, if that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that does what you ask for.
The main problem is to assemble the new names from the old names' path and file extension. This is done with functions

- `basename` and `dirname` in package `base`;
- `file_ext` and `file_path_sans_ext` in package `tools`.

The consecutive numbers are produced by `seq_along`. Then `paste0`, `sprintf` and `file.path` put everything together.

If you want all numbers to have the same number of digits, change the format part of the `fmt_string` string to `"%04d.%s"`.

```
file_rename_custom <- function(path, pattern, prefix = "Animals") {
  files_vec <- list.files(path = path, pattern = pattern, full.names = TRUE)
  ext <- tools::file_ext(files_vec)
  fname <- files_vec |>
    basename() |> 
    tools::file_path_sans_ext()
  
  fmt_string <- paste0(prefix, "%0", length(files_vec), "d.%s")
  new_name <- sprintf(fmt_string, seq_along(fname), ext)
  new_name <- file.path(dirname(files_vec), new_name)
  
  file.rename(files_vec, new_name)
}

working_directory <- getwd()
wd1 <- file.path(working_directory, "animals/photos")
wd2 <- file.path(working_directory, "animals")

dir(wd1)
# [1] "Cat.txt"    "Chiken.txt" "Moose.txt" 
file_rename_custom(wd1, "\\.txt")
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
dir(wd1)
# [1] "Animals1.txt" "Animals2.txt" "Animals3.txt"

dir(wd2)
# [1] "Cat.txt"    "Chiken.txt" "Moose.txt"  "photos"    
file_rename_custom(wd2, "\\.txt")
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
dir(wd2)
# [1] "Animals1.txt" "Animals2.txt" "Animals3.txt" "photos"
```

Comment: Incredible! Coding was more complex than I thought it would be but worked exactly how I needed it too. Thank you Rui!!!

Comment: Rui, I've been using your code but realise that each time I relabel a folder, the rearranges the sequence of the files, seemingly at random. Do you know why that is? I tried to use pattern = FALSE, but this did not work

Comment: @zappbran The files new order is probably not random, it just so happens that `"Animals10"` sorts before `"Animals2"`. The numeric order is not what it seems. I think I have corrected this, try now after the edited `paste0` instruction in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your problem:

```
file.rename(from = Sys.glob(file.path(original_path, "*.png")), 
            to = file.path(original_path, paste0("Animal", seq_along(files), ".png")))
```